# JQuery when() with error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is way to use JQuery when with 200 HTTP response:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ), $.ajax( "test2.aspx" ) ).done(function( ) {
  alert( 'asd' ); // Alerts "123"
});
```

But how to use this if I get other than 200 response? E.g. where to add callback for errors?

Comment: use `.fail()` e.g You could use `then(success,error)` or `always()` but better would be to read the DOC

Comment: Am I missing something? What you're saying here is "when I've created this object, alert the key `testing`". There's nothing about AJAX in here or anything that would measure responses?

Comment: @h2ooooooo you are right, posted code doesn't make any sense

Comment: Code sample is from docs

Comment: @user2846569 ok but it is a counter example

Comment: The sample was just to say what I am talking about, fail() was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery allows you to program against an error as in the comments:

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});
```

If you want to target status codes yourself you could go down following road, again from Docs.

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

Can add status codes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

You need to check for jqXHR.status, and add your callback there.